# How to Match mutilple line string using Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex, multi-select, multiline

I have a below 2 lines :

> /begin MEASUREMENT **ANYNAME1** "Unterstützungskraft Softwaremodul "
>
> SWORD **ANYNAME2** 1 100 -**Randomdigits1** **Randomdigits2**

and I want to match **ANYNAME1** , **ANYNAME2**  , **Randomdigits1**  and **Randomdigits2**

So far I am able to match **ANYNAME1** in first line using below regex :

```
_regex_struct = re.compile(r'/begin MEASUREMENT (.*)(.*)\n')
```

but i am not able to go to the second line. How to match the expression on second line??

Comment: Could you provide us with more example of the input? So we can see the pattern. Are both `Randomdigits` integer?

Comment: What's the result do you expect?

Comment: They can be float and negative number as well.

Comment: I expect ANYNAME1 , ANYNAME2 , Randomdigits1 and Randomdigits2 in group(1), group(2), group(3), group(4)

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/lbaUpX/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just make an assumption with your input. You may check the [RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/mb5Kur/2).

```
inputstr = '''/begin MEASUREMENT ANYNAME1 "Unterstützungskraft Softwaremodul "  
SWORD ANYNAME2 1 100 -2342342523 2432343535654
'''
_regex_struct = re.compile(r'/begin\s+MEASUREMENT\s+(?P<name1>[\w.]+)\W.*\nSWORD\s+(?P<name2>[\w.]+)\W.+\s+(?P<digit1>-\d.+|\d.+)\s+(?P<digit2>-\d.+|\d.+)')
_regex_struct.findall(inputstr)
```

Output:

```
[('ANYNAME1', 'ANYNAME2', '-2342342523', '2432343535654')]
```

Explanation of the expression:

> `\s` = any whitespace character
>
> `(?P<>)` = to create a group of the expected output
>
> `\w` = any word character
>
> `\W` = any non-word character
>
> `\d` = any digit
>
> `+` = to express one or more

Comment: Can you please explain the expression you used?

Comment: Thanks!! How to match when ANYNAME1  can have 2 formats : "ABC.DEF" or "ABCDEF" ?

Comment: I changed the regex

Answer (score 1):

```
In [20]: s = '''/begin MEASUREMENT ANYNAME1 "Unterstützungskraft Softwaremodul "
    ...: SWORD ANYNAME2 1 100 -Randomdigits1 Randomdigits2'''

In [31]: re_struct = re.compile(r'/begin MEASUREMENT (\w+)[\s\S]*?SWORD (\w+).*?100 -(\w+) (\w+)')

In [32]: m = re_struct.search(s)

In [33]: m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4)
Out[33]: ('ANYNAME1', 'ANYNAME2', 'Randomdigits1', 'Randomdigits2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match ANYNAME1 in a capturing group in the first line, then use `.*` to get to the end of the line and use `\n` to match a new line to get to the second line. There you could match and capture your values using 3 groups.

```
/begin MEASUREMENT ([\w.]+).*\nSWORD ([\w.]+) \d+ \d+ (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fdkNJH/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gKprKD)

**Explanation**

- `/begin MEASUREMENT` Match literally followed by a space
- `([\w.]+).*\n` Capture 1+ word chars or a dot in group 1 and match until the end of the string. Then match a newline
- `SWORD ([\w.]+)` Match SWORD and capture in group 2 1+ times a word char or dot
- `\d+ \d+` Match space, 1+ digits, space, 1+ digits space
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture in group 3 and 4 an optional minus sign, 1+ digits and an optional decimal part whith a space in between

For example:

```
import re

regex = r"/begin MEASUREMENT ([\w.]+).*\nSWORD ([\w.]+) \d+ \d+ (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
test_str = ("/begin MEASUREMENT ANY.NAME1 \"Unterstützungskraft Softwaremodul \"\n"
    "SWORD ANYN.AME2 1 100 -2342342523 -14.29")
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))

# [('ANY.NAME1', 'ANYN.AME2', '-2342342523', '-14.29')]
```